# calling a string as a function in openoffice-calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

I don't normally program in openoffice, but I thought I'd give it a shot since it's convenient for the end user. My problem is the following: I have copied the txt of a command into a cell and modified the command string so that it updates with corrected information. The updated cell output is ex:

```
INDEX(B4:C101,MATCH(MIN(C4:C101),C4:C101,0),1)
```

-

This, however, needs to be run as an index function. I tried removing the index and referencing the cell with `R2 = B4:C101,MATCH(MIN(C4:C101),C4:C101,0),1`, so that would be a cell with `=INDEX(R2)`, but it didn't work. I think it's because each argument needs to be input separately when linking to cells.

Short of rewritng the whole thing in three separate linked cells to update with individual arguments and link the index function column as `=INDEX(R1,R2,R3,0)`, where `R1 = B4:C101`, `R2 = MATCH(MIN(C4:C101)`,and `R3= C4:C101,0),1` is there any way to input a string and run it as if it were all 4 arguments of the index function?

Answer (score 1):

OpenOffice Calc usually uses a semi-colon rather than a comma to separate arguements in a function. You could put both values into R1 (separated by a space) and parse the text out to be used by `INDIRECT` to generate4 cell/range addresses.

With `B4:B101 C4:C101` in R1 this should do.

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(LEFT(R1; FIND(" "; R1)-1)); MATCH(MIN(INDIRECT(MID(R1; FIND(" "; R1)+1; 9))); INDIRECT(MID(R1; FIND(" "; R1)+1; 9)); 0))
```